# Distributed File System (DFS) Shared Drive Disappears at Logon for Users in a Given Organizational Unit (OU)

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

So, I've got a bit of an odd problem, and I want to get a grasp on the cause and what the solution is before it gets any worse.

We've got a DFS share that's set to be mapped to all users in our domain via Group Policy Object (GPO). However, today, with no recent Group Policy changes made, 3 users in a specific OU have reported that the shared drive was gone at logon from their lists. We have manually added it back in each user's case and this fixes the problem for the session, as it's not an issue of the computer being unable to see the drive.

The only other GPO that affects mapped drives in our domain is one for home folders/personal documents, which are still showing up correctly.

The policy that controls mapping of the DFS share was enabled but not enforced on this particular OU initially, however even after enforcing the policy on this OU, the policy has yet to be picked up by the account I'm testing it with after running through a gpupdate /force cycle 6 times.

End user OS is Windows 7 Pro x64.

Domain is a Server 2012 R2 domain.

Comment: Is the GPO a computer policy or user policy?

Comment: It's a user policy.

Turns out it's not just a single OU.

Comment: Also, we found the cause and I'll be posting the answer in a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this affected more than one OU and it simply had not been reported to us by anyone not in the OU mentioned until this morning. It's caused by KB 3159398.

Comment: Did you see that there is a resolution for it? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3159398

Comment: Yes, and it had been applied when I posted that answer.